# Why is TypeScript import resulting in a 404

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm at the end of my understanding here.

I have an existing asp.net core app with plain ol' javascript from which I'm trying to write a POC for migrating to Typescript. I've converted a couple .js files to .ts files with what looks like the appropriate code. The output is quite similar.

However, when trying to use one of the exported classes from a `.ts` file as an import to another `.ts` file, all is as it should be at compile time, but when I run the app, I get a **404** on the imported `.ts` module.

### Source

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/Scripts",
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "module": "amd"
  },
  "include": [
    "Client"
  ]
}
```

**What I understand to be my requirejs configuration**

```
requirejs.config({
    urlArgs: "v0.3",
    baseUrl: "/Scripts",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "lib/jquery-3.3.1.min",
        "knockout": "lib/knockout-3.5.0.min",
        "bootstrap": "lib/bootstrap.bundle-4.3.1.min",
        "text": "lib/text",
        "telemetry": "lib/sybTelemetry",
        "jsgrid": "lib/jsgrid-1.5.3.min",
        "sybModal": "lib/sybModal",
        "sybMessageBus": "lib/sybMessageBus",
        "newSybModal": "app/lib/newSybModal"
    },
    shim: {
        "jsgrid": ["jquery"]
    }
});
```

Which is on my `_Layout.cshtml` thus:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/lib/require-2.3.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/requireConfig.js"></script>
```

Client\app\home\home\**HomeViewModel2.ts**

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import { IApplication } from "./Application";
import { SybModal } from "../../lib/sybModal";

function HomeViewModel2() {
    let applications: KnockoutObservableArray<IApplication> = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON("/home/LoadApplications")
        .done(apps => this.applications().push(apps))
        .fail((obj, testStatus, error) => {
            (new SybModal()).showError("Error getting applications", obj);
        });
}
```

The `import {SybModal} from "../../lib/sybModal";` is what autocomplete suggests to me after typing `sybModal`, so like I said at build time, it is known to exist in that location, but something is different with run time.

**Resulting HomeViewModel2.js** because I think this is the offending file

```
define(["require", "exports", "jquery", "../../lib/sybModal"], function (require, exports, $, sybModal_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    function HomeViewModel2() {
        var _this = this;
        var applications = ko.observableArray([]);
        $.getJSON("/home/LoadApplications")
            .done(function (apps) { return _this.applications().push(apps); })
            .fail(function (obj, testStatus, error) {
            (new sybModal_1.SybModal()).showError("Error getting applications", obj);
        });
    }
```

**sybModal.ts**

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import * as b_ from "bootstrap";

export class SybModal {
    showError(msg: string, httpObj: JQueryXHR) {
        if (msg === null || msg.length === 0) {
            msg = "";
        }

        msg += "<br />";

        if (httpObj === null) {
            msg += "An unknown error occurred" + "<br />";
        } else {
            if (httpObj.statusText !== null) {
                msg += httpObj.statusText + "<br />";
            }

            if (httpObj.responseText !== null) {
                msg += httpObj.responseText + "<br />";
            }
        }

        $("#errorModalMessage").html(msg);
        $("#errorModal").modal("show");
    }

    showInformation(title: string, message: string) {
        $("#informationModalTitle").html(title);
        $("#informationModalMessage").html(message);
        $("#informationModal").modal("show");
    }
}
```

The **Index.cshtm**

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/app/home/home/HomeViewModel2.js"></script>
}

<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: applications">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3 class="card-title" data-bind="text: name"></h3>
                <p class="card-text" data-bind="text: description"></p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="attr:{href:link}">Go</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### The Error

[image]

Comment: And where's SybModal compilation placed?

Comment: the `tsconfig.json` has `"outDir": "wwwroot/Scripts",` so it lands in `wwwroot/Scripts/app/lib/SybModal.js`. Basically the folder structure under `Client/` in my image illustration is copied to `wwwroot/Scripts`.

Comment: So it's RequireJS failing to fetch the script by relative path set as `define` param. How is it configured then?

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean? The `.js` calling `requirejs.config({...})`?

Comment: No, what's the actual configuration? See, some of your scripts are loaded directly, but some (their deps) are loaded by RequireJS through `define` function. Now we need to know which paths are setup as base ones for RequireJS.

Comment: @raina77ow I've added the contents of my `requireConfig.js`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199444/discussion-between-josh-gust-and-raina77ow).

Comment: So what was the solution in the end?